# Same execution plan?

Tags: t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I am studying to become a database administrator, in doing so, I want to learn a bit more about tuning queries. Most I am able to figure out but I wanted to see why these two queries have the same execution plan even written two different ways. These are based off the `adventureworks2012lt` database.

```
select productnumber, name, listprice 
from saleslt.product
where productnumber like 'bk-[a-q,s-z]%' and productnumber like '%-[0-9][0-9]'


SELECT ProductNumber, Name, ListPrice
FROM SalesLT.Product 
WHERE ProductNumber LIKE 'BK-[^R]%-[0-9][0-9]';
```

I cant post photos yet because my rep is not high enough yet :(

Comment: They are even the same logical reads:
(54 row(s) affected)
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 103, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(54 row(s) affected)
Table 'Product'. Scan count 1, logical reads 103, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: I will just say, SQL server engine is smarter than you think it is.

Comment: Two like searches on productnumber with a wild card and you are surprised it has the same execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are manually browsing through a product catalog, looking for Product Number of the pattern you specified. The products are not sorted in any order. What choice do you have other than going through all products and match them one by one? You have no index on `ProductNumber`. SQL Server has no choice but do a table scan to find matching rows.

But what will happen if you add an index to `ProductNumber`? The result would have been the same anyway. Patterns starting with `%` cannot utilize the index. So your first query will jump to the range in the index that starts with `BK`. And so will your second query.

Newcomers are obsessed with making things efficient. Over time, you will learn to leave things to SQL Server. You should only worry about things when they do become a problem. The only exception is cursor. If you think about using cursors to solve a problem, it's the wrong approach 90% of the time.

Comment: A few things I would like to add 1) The database does have a unique, non-clustered index located on the productnumber column. This means that you should be more efficient with the second query correct? Since you cant use the index when the like clause starts with a "%".

2) I don't believe that you should leave the queries alone until they become a problem. After all, you could be putting in an efficient execution plan for one query and when you change variables it will be a terrible execution plan. (AKA poor code coverage and parameter sniffing)

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth. Know good practices for writing good query, then leave the rest for the database. There will always be fringe cases where your queries slow to a craw. I won't care if a query jumps from 1s to 2s (a 100% increase) until the business says it's a problem. I can better spend my efforts somewhere else.

Comment: Wrt to your first point: yes, the 2nd condition in the first query is SARGEABLE, but the 1st is. So both query will jump to the range that starts with BK and continue from there. What happens next is really hard to say: is it more efficient evaluating 2 simple conditions or 1 complex condition? To have a definite answer you need to benchmark it over millions of rows and then the difference may be too small to matter at all.